# WCF - There was no endpoint listening

Tags: wcf, endpoint, endpoint-address

One of my WCF Services has an operation contract taking a large sized file as a parameter. So, when the client tries to send this over, I got an exception and when I looked at the server trace this is what I saw:

> MESSAGE: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536)
>   has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the
>   MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I was using the default simplified configuration for my WCF services, so added a new service definition as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <endpoint address="MyService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
      contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"
             maxBufferSize="10485760"
             maxBufferPoolSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="10485760"
           maxStringContentLength="10485760"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  ...
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    ...
</protocolMapping>
```

The way I consume my services is, I have a function returning a channel in my helper class, and I use that channel to call the operations:

```
public static T CreateChannel<T>() where T : IBaseService
{
    System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding= new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();

    binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
    binding.Security = new BasicHttpSecurity() { Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None };
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = 10485760;

    System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<T> cf2 = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, 
             new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(MyEndpointAddress)); //I checked this part, the address is correct.
    T Channel= cf2.CreateChannel();
    return Channel;
}
```

and then,

```
var businessObject = WcfHelper.CreateChannel<IMyService>();
var operationResult = await businessObject.MyOperationAsync(...);
```

Even though, my other services are running correctly, the one I defined in the configuration explicitly returns an exception of *"There was no endpoint listening..."* I am developing on VS2012, using IISExpress. What may be the problem, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mismatch for transfert mode. In client-side, you are are using streamed transfert whereas in server-side it is not in the config. In addition, you have specified 10MB, which is not so high.

Please visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) for more info on streaming.

**Edit :**

If you are hosting under IIS, please also check (default is 4Mb) :

```
<system.web>    
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096 " />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the article but the transfer mode setting makes no difference, I was just trying different things + the file that I pass as a parameter is way larger than 65536 bytes and smaller than 10MB.